# Range check error when creating GIST index on tsrange value

Tags: postgresql, indexing, gist, range-checking

Fixing range bound data and creating gist tsrange index causes exception. I can guess the PostgreSQL sees old version of records and takes them into account when creating the gist index.

You can reproduce it using this script:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE  TABLE _test_gist_range_index("from" timestamp(0) WITHOUT time zone, "till" timestamp(0) WITHOUT time zone);
--let's enter some invalid data
INSERT INTO _test_gist_range_index VALUES ('2021-01-02', '2021-01-01');
--let's fix the data
DELETE FROM _test_gist_range_index;
CREATE INDEX idx_range_idx_test2 ON _test_gist_range_index USING gist (tsrange("from", "till", '[]'));
COMMIT;
```

The result  is:

```
SQL Error [22000]: ERROR: range lower bound must be less than or equal to range upper bound
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c7531114c99c635371f5975a659ef826)

I've tested this on all versions of PostgreSQL  starting from v9.5 and ending with v13 using db<>fiddle. The result is the same on all of them.

The same error is received if we fix the data using "UPDATE".

Is there a way to fix the data and have range index on it? Maybe there is a way to clean the table somehow from those old values?..

**EDIT**

It seems that the exception is raised only if data correcting statements (`DELETE` in my example) and `CREATE INDEX` statement are in the same transaction. If I `DELETE` and `COMMIT` first, and then creating the index succeeds.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - the point is I **do delete all the records** from the table, but still get the error (please see the example). The same is when I update the incorrect data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - yes, that's the point:
1. we have a table with incorrect data, 2. we fix the data, 3. we still can't use range index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - let's be constructive. I've provided the reproducible example of the problem I face. You can clearly see I delete all the records from the table using the `DELETE` statement, so no invalid data is left on it. If it is somehow not done correctly - please point it out. What more can I provide do clear up the situation?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=750fe73f8ce37285be4e959b62c79902

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=56d1ce754abb7a6f71ebf8dda69de419  - I took your example and moved the `CREATE INDEX` statement to the `DELETE` batch  and the problem returned. I've experimented a bit with my DB and it seems the exception is raised when the `DELETE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements are in the same transaction. Does that explain the behavior? It still seems wrong, because you can for example remove duplicates and add unique index on a table in a single transaction without an error... ( https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=39f80cb08ec03a5fab37022aee4716a8 )

Comment: I just tested with 13.3, and your script runs just fine, without any error, just as I would expect. There must be some mistake on your end.

Comment: Thank you for your involvement. Did you run the script in a single transaction? It seems to be essential that the data correcting statements and create index statement to be in a single transaction.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe I've installed  PostgreSQL 13.3 - executed the script and got exception. Please confirm you executed the script in a single transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is working as expected and not a bug.

When you delete a row in a PostgreSQL table, it is not actually deleted, but marked as invisible. Similarly, updating a row creates a new version of the row, but the old version is retained and marked invisible. This is the way how PostgreSQL implements multiversioning: concurrent transactions can still see the "invisible" data. Eventually, invisible rows are reclaimed by `VACUUM`.

Now a B-tree or GiST index contains one entry for each row version in the table, unless the row version is not visible by anybody (is *dead*). This explains why a deleted row will still cause an error if the data don't form a valid range.

If you run the statements in autocommit mode on an otherwise idle database, the deleted rows are dead, and no index entry has to be created.

Comment: I was convinced that deleted rows are not taken into index because you can remove dublicates and add unique index in the same transaction, but I guess that is a special case. If you added a link to a documentation describing how B-tree and GiST operate it would even improve your answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is not a special link - that is how MVCC works in PostgreSQL. Imagine you are inside a `REPEATABLE READ` transaction. Now someone deletes a row from a table. Then you still have to be able to see the row during in your transaction, even if you perform an index scan.